# regular expression to segregate chat between two person in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a string:

"mary g: hello dr ydeen how can i help you   dany: hi is there a place within the physician portal to see how many vacation and sick hours i currently have thank you so much for your time    mary g: yes you can view that in your secure hr page under benefits summary first youll have to enter the last four of your ssn on the right hand side youll be directed to your secure hr page and on the left hand side there will be a list of links select benefits summary    mary g: you can also view it on each pay stub biweekly    dany: i thought it might be on the paystub i can never seem to find it there : checking out benefits summary now    dany: great i see vacation and sick time here to confirm this is how much i have currently accrued    mary g: youll have to select the quotprintviewquot option on the paycheck and the accruals are listed under your earnings    mary g: great yes thats correct    mary g: its your accruals as of the last pay period    mary g: so currently its accurate up until     dany: perfect thank you so much and noted regarding printview    dany: thanks so much for your help    mary g: my pleasure anything else i can help you with    dany: thats all thanks again    mary g: have a great day"

I want to extract all chat written by mary g, I tried below regex but its only giving first line string

```r
text_agnt=gsub(".*^[[:alpha:]][^:]+:\\s*|\\s[A-Za-z]{3,10}:.*$","",text)
```

Output: "hello dr ydeen how can i help you  "

Expected output: all text written by mary g

Comment: Try  using a capturing group `\bmary\s+g:\s*(.*?)(?=\s{2}[^:]*:|$)` https://regex101.com/r/dRvuBF/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example data, there are more than 2 whitespace chars before the name and the colon. In that case you can use a positive lookahead assertion to check what follows is either 2 whitespace chars followed by a `:` with at least a single `[A-Za-z]` before it,  or the end of the string.

```
\bmary\s+g:\s*(.*?)(?=\s{2}[^:]*[A-Za-z]:|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL8FZF/1)

```
library(stringr)

txt <- "mary g: hello dr ydeen how can i help you   dany: hi is there a place within the physician portal to see how many vacation and sick hours i currently have thank you so much for your time    mary g: yes you can view that in your secure hr page under benefits summary first youll have to enter the last four of your ssn on the right hand side youll be directed to your secure hr page and on the left hand side there will be a list of links select benefits summary    mary g: you can also view it on each pay stub biweekly    dany: i thought it might be on the paystub i can never seem to find it there : checking out benefits summary now    dany: great i see vacation and sick time here to confirm this is how much i have currently accrued    mary g: youll have to select the quotprintviewquot option on the paycheck and the accruals are listed under your earnings    mary g: great yes thats correct    mary g: its your accruals as of the last pay period    mary g: so currently its accurate up until     dany: perfect thank you so much and noted regarding printview    dany: thanks so much for your help    mary g: my pleasure anything else i can help you with    dany: thats all thanks again    mary g: have a great day"
pattern <- "\\bmary\\s+g:\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s{2}[^:]*[A-Za-z]:|$)"
str_match_all(txt, pattern)[[1]][,2]
```

Output

```
[1] "hello dr ydeen how can i help you"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[2] "yes you can view that in your secure hr page under benefits summary first youll have to enter the last four of your ssn on the right hand side youll be directed to your secure hr page and on the left hand side there will be a list of links select benefits summary"
[3] "you can also view it on each pay stub biweekly"                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[4] "youll have to select the quotprintviewquot option on the paycheck and the accruals are listed under your earnings"                                                                                                                                                      
[5] "great yes thats correct"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[6] "its your accruals as of the last pay period"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[7] "so currently its accurate up until"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[8] "my pleasure anything else i can help you with"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[9] "have a great day"
```

Comment: Thanks, do you see any pattern for extracting the chat by Dany for above?

Comment: @Nishant Like this? https://regex101.com/r/SNbizT/1

Comment: Ok, that's going to work with specific name, but I have multiple strings with different names, mary g and dany is just an example it could be anything but name is going to be in same order, for customer (first name and last name(one char), and dr. name will contain only first name)

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to do it for random name too, thanks for the help

Comment: @Nishant Sure, you might use this https://regex101.com/r/eCnaN8/1 In the pattern you have to specify what is allowed before the colon. This `\b[^:]*` is a very broad match matching any char except a `:` This pattern would be a bit stricter matching only word characters separated by whitespace chars https://regex101.com/r/BhtBEG/1 `\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)*:\s*(.*?)(?=\s{2}[^:]*[A-Za-z]:|$)`